# Syntax error near unexpected token `fi' in command

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create a command which lists the first or last n lines (number specified by the user) of every file in a directory which is also specified by the user. They also have the option of using head or tail.

```
HEADORTAIL=$1

NUMLINES=$2

DIRECTORY=$3

if [ $# -lt 3 ]
then
      echo "The command needs three arguments to work"
      echo "The usage of this command is as follows: lshead [-head or -tail] [n$
      exit
elif [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]
then
    echo "This directory exists"
    while [ $2 -lt 1 ] ; do
            echo "The number of lines you wish to see must be greater than 0"
            read $2
    done
if [ $1 == "-head" ]
then
    head -$2 $HOME/$3/*
elif [ $1 == "-tail" ]
then
    tail -$2 $HOME/$3/*
    exit
fi
fi
fi
fi
exit
```

I don't really know what to expect in terms of an answer from the terminal. Apologies if I have made any mistakes or done anything stupid. I am relatively knew to bash shell scripting and to this site.

I get this error when I run the command.

```
lshead3 -head 10 bin
./lshead3: line 30: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
./lshead3: line 30: `fi'
```

Just got this when I put it into ShellCheck

```
$ shellcheck myscript

    Line 9:
        echo "The usage of this command is as follows: lshead [-head or -tail] [n$
        ^-- SC1009: The mentioned parser error was in this simple command.
             ^-- SC1078: Did you forget to close this double quoted string?

    Line 11:
    elif [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]
          ^-- SC1079: This is actually an end quote, but due to next char it looks suspect.
                     ^-- SC1078: Did you forget to close this double quoted string?

    Line 13:
        echo "This directory exists"
             ^-- SC1079: This is actually an end quote, but due to next char it looks suspect.

    Line 21:
    elif [ $1 == "-tail" ]
                   ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this double quoted string.

    Line 28:

^-- SC1072: Expected end of double quoted string. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.

$
```

Comment: You only have two ifs but four fis. That doesn’t add up

Comment: Whenever you have a shell syntax error, a good first step is to cut and paste your code into
[shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)
and correct the errors (important) and warnings (might be important) that it identifies. If you have trouble understanding its messages, then come here and ask.

Comment: Ive just edited it and now it doesn't do anything. Its better than getting errors I suppose. Can you help me further please? Also could you recommend some ways I could tidy the code up please?

Comment: @John1024 could you have a look at my edit to my question please?

Comment: It's right there in Shellcheck's output: "SC1078: Did you forget to close this double quoted string?"

Comment: @JohnKugelman Ah it seems some of the echo has been missed out. I have actually closed that. That was just a copy paste error from me. The other issues are still there

Comment: @AdnanSaddique In shellcheck, the errors (red) are most important. After you fix the missing quote, shellcheck will tell you that you should add a shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) to declare which shell you are using and that there is an `fi` which doesn't match any `if`.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 1):

```
  1 #!/bin/bash

  2 head_or_tail=$1
  3 num_lines=$2
  4 directory=$3
  5
  6 if [ $# -ne 3 ]
  7 then
  8     echo "The command needs three arguments to work"
  9     echo "The usage of this command is as follows: lshead [head or tail] [numlines] [directory]"
 10     exit 1
 11 fi
 12
 13
 14 if [[ "$num_lines" -lt 1 ]]
 15 then
 16     echo "The number of lines you wish to see must be greater than 0"
 17     exit 1
 18 fi
 19
 20 if [[ ! -d "$directory" ]]
 21 then
 22     echo "Directory $directory does not exist"
 23     exit 1
 24 else
 25     echo "looking in directoy $directory"
 26     if [[ "$head_or_tail" = "head" ]]
 27     then
 28         head -n "$num_lines" "$directory"/*
 29     elif [[ "$head_or_tail" = "tail" ]]
 30     then
 31         tail -n "$num_lines" "$directory"/*
 32     fi
 33 fi
 34 exit
```

NOTE:

- Line 2-4: You store your command line arguments into variables, so that you use them downwards, and keep your code readable and easy to understand
- Line 6: Use `-ne` instead of `-lt`. This will ensure your script fails even if number of arguments is more than 3 (not only less than 3)
- You don't need to use `read` (read man page of `read`) in your code since you are not reading lines from `fd`. You need the values of your arguments which you are anyway storing in the variables in Line: 2-4
- if you use a `while` loop, make sure the condition fails upon completion so that execution breaks out of the loop. The way to do that is using increment or decrement counters which you are not using in your code
- Make sure that you pass absolute path of the directory as the third argument. That way you won't have to use `$HOME` in your code, when you `head` or `tail`
- The correct way to use `head` to show first `n` lines in `head -n [numlines]`, same goes with `tail`

IMPORTANT: Also read Charles Duffy comments below, he pointed out really important things, that must not be missed.

Comment: There are some bugs you aren't fixing -- this won't work with directory names that contain spaces, for example, due to the lack of quoting; and using `==` instead of `=` inside of `[` makes code needlessly bash-specific (the only POSIX-defined string comparison operator is just `=`). So `head -n $NUMLINES $DIRECTORY/*` should instead be `head -n "$NUMLINES" "$DIRECTORY/"*`, for example. (All-upper-case names for user-defined variables are [contrary to POSIX-specified convention](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html), but that's a larger issue).

Comment: The bigger issue, though, is that this isn't a question that meets our quality bar to be eligible to be answered. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions". Questions that fail to isolate a single, specific question should be pushed back to the OP to clarify and improve.

Comment: (To explain why a specification that speaks directly to environment variables applies to regular shell variables as well -- setting a value for any variable that already exists in the environment will automatically `export` the new value; consequently, namespace conventions apply in both places. Quoting the specific, relevant lines: *The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications. Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities.*)

Comment: ...btw, you might consider exiting with a nonzero status on error, and redirecting error-related text to stderr.

Comment: @Charles Duffy, totally agree with the points you mentioned. Made the edits. I quickly just fixed the code given in the question. We must conform to the standards. Thanks a lot for pointing it out.

Comment: Yup -- still a bad question, but this is a good answer. Thank you for your effort, and welcome to StackOverflow! :)

Comment: Thanks for the help @AshutoshBharti. The code you gave me works perfectly apart from one issue. If there is a directory (A) within a directory (B) it only reads the lines of the files in directory A, not B. What would I need to add to make this possible?

Comment: @AdnanSaddique check if you missed any closing quote. Not necessarily on line 31. I checked the code at `https://www.shellcheck.net/`. No issues were detected.

Comment: @AshutoshBharti could you explain that in more detail please? How would I add that into my script?

Comment: @AdnanSaddique for reading recursively, you will have to go to each directory, find the files and use head and tail there. A way to achieve that can be like this: `find . -type f | while read f; do tail -n "$num_lines" "$f"/*` 

But you can achieve in other ways too

Comment: @AshutoshBharti Ok ill have a go at using that. I appreciate the help. Thank you :)

Comment: @AdnanSaddique infact you can do this entire thing in one line with the command I told above
`find [directory] -type f | while read f; do tail -n [num_lines] "$f";done`
for `head` just replace `tail` with `head`.

So what it does is, in the `directory` it finds all files ( `-type f` is for that), reads the file, then perform head or tail over that file.

Comment: Ok so in the new code you gave me already where would I put the edit you just posted? @AshutoshBharti

Comment: @AdnanSaddique
 `24 else
 25     echo "looking in directoy $directory"
 26     if [[ "$head_or_tail" = "head" ]]
 27     then
 28         find "$firectory" -type f | while read f; do head -n "$num_lines" "$f"; done
 29     elif [[ "$head_or_tail" = "tail" ]]
 30     then
 31         find "$directory" -type f | while read f; do tail -n "$num_lines" "$f"; done
 32     fi
 33 fi
 34 exit`

Comment: @AshutoshBharti Ok it works now to the point where it can look into directories within other directions but I have lost the headings that appear to indicate which file's line's are being listed. I have been making backups every time I change the command so I can easily go back to the other one but if you could help me further I would be grateful

Comment: @AdnanSaddique
`28 find "$firectory" -type f | while read f; do echo "---- $f ----"; head -n "$num_lines" "$f"; done 29 elif [[ "$head_or_tail" = "tail" ]] 30 then 31 find "$directory" -type f | while read f; do echo "---- $f ----"; tail -n "$num_lines" "$f"; done`

Comment: `find . -type f | while read f; do` doesn't work properly if filenames contain literal backslashes or literal newlines, or leading or trailing whitespace. Instead, use `find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do`.

Comment: Or you can use `find . -type f -exec tail -n "$num_lines" {} +`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I admire you man, how come you know this much. Can you guide me, pls. **foldedhands **

Answer (score 0):

```
find [directory] -type f | while read f; do tail -n [num_lines] "$f"; done
```

similarly,

```
find [directory] -type f | while read f; do head -n [num_lines] "$f"; done
```